# Array of JSON to Tree-structure JSON of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, treemap

I want to write the function which can take an array of JSON to tree-structure JSON of array.

I have an Array of JSON like this:

```
    var rawData = [{
    "dimension": ["a", "c", "f"],
    "metric": [26]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "b", "e"],
    "metric": [12]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "d", "e"],
    "metric": [7]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "b", "f"],
    "metric": [5]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "c", "e"],
    "metric": [2]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "d", "f"],
    "metric": [1]
}, {
    "dimension": ["a", "k", ""],
    "metric": [2]
},{
    "dimension": ["b", "c", "d"],
    "metric": [2]
}];
```

I'm expecting output like this:

```
output:
{
    name: 'start',
    children: [{
            name: 'a',
            children: [{
                    name: 'c',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'f',
                        value: 26
                    }, {
                        name: 'e',
                        value: 2
                    }]
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'e',
                        value: 12
                    }, {
                        name: 'f',
                        value: 5
                    }]
                },
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'e',
                        value: 7
                    }, {
                        name: 'f',
                        value: 1
                    }]
                },
                {
                    name: 'k',
                    value: 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'b',
            children: [{
                name: 'c',
                children: [{
                    name: 'd',
                    value: 2
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me with a small query. I don't think that we need more details regarding this.
If you want any other feel free to comment on this post.

**Edit:**
To make the question more simple to understand.

**Edit my code**

```
var output = {
    name: "start",
    children: []
};
var len = rawData.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    rawChild = rawData[i];
    cat = createJson({}, rawChild.dimension.filter(n => n), rawChild.metric[0]);
    if (i == 0)
        output.children.push(cat);
    else {
        mergeData(output, output.children, cat);
    }
}


function mergeData(parent, child, cat) {
    if (child) {
        for (var index = 0; index < child.length; index++) {
            var element = child[index];

            if (cat.children) {
                if (element.name == cat.name) {
                    parent = mergeData(element, element.children, cat.children[0]);
                    return parent;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                if (element.name == cat.name) {
                    parent = mergeData(element, element.children, cat);
                    return parent;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
        parent.children.push(cat);
        return parent;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
console.log(util.inspect(output, false, null, true));

function createJson(mainObj, names, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(names)) {
        mainObj.name = names;
        mainObj.value = value;
        return mainObj;
    } else {
        for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
            if (index == names.length - 1) {
                mainObj = createJson(mainObj, names[index], value);
            } else {
                mainObj.name = names[index];
                newarr = names;
                newarr.shift();
                mainObj.children = [createJson({}, newarr, value)];
            }
        }
    }
    return mainObj;
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What's your algorithm to arrive at the output?

Comment: I'm adding my code in post to understand it more easily

Comment: I want to know about a more optimized way to do this.

Comment: Can you please post the expected output in words to create a [mcve]? Reverse engineering your code is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a nested loop approach by iterating `rawData` and the `dimention` array while saving the last item for the final object and reduce the other given names until the final children array is found.

In the inner lopp, a lookup is made for a children of the same name and if not found, a new data set is generated and inserted.

The use of an external check for childrrem helps for shorter pathes, which have no children properties.

```js
var rawData = [{ dimension: ["a", "c", "f"], metric: [26] }, { dimension: ["a", "b", "e"], metric: [12] }, { dimension: ["a", "d", "e"], metric: [7] }, { dimension: ["a", "b", "f"], metric: [5] }, { dimension: ["a", "c", "e"], metric: [2] }, { dimension: ["a", "d", "f"], metric: [1] }, { dimension: ["a", "k", ""], metric: [2] }, { dimension: ["b", "c", "d"], metric: [2] }],
    result = { name: "start", children: [] };

rawData.forEach(({ dimension: path, metric: [value] }) => {
    while (!path[path.length - 1]) path.pop(); // remove falsy values from end
    var name = path.pop();
    path
        .reduce((result, name) => {
            var temp = result.find(o => o.name === name);
            if (!temp) {
                result.push(temp = { name });
            }
            temp.children = temp.children || [];
            return temp.children;
        }, result.children)
        .push({ name, value });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```